# While Calling through crontab mail is not going from ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, cron, postfix-mta

I Am trying to call a shell script through crontab. And from shellscript I am calling a command for running a ruby code.

~/process.sh

```
    ruby ~/program.rb
```

In ruby code am checking a process is running and if not trying to send a mail.

```
result = `ps aux | grep unicorn`
unless result.match(/unicorn_rails master -c config\/unicorn\/unicorn_development.rb -E   development -D/)
   `echo "Stopped" | mail -s "a subject" someone@somedomain.com`
end
```

When I trying to run the shell script from terminal it is sending mail perfectly. But from crontab the call is happening but mail is not going.

Inside crontab am calling the shell script like

```
00 */1    * * *   ~/process.sh
```

please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Are you sure it can find `~/program.rb` as the `~` is for current user's root directory? Try to use full path here.

Comment: what's they output generated by the following crontab entry: * * * * * which ruby > /tmp/which_ruby.txt

Comment: Using the exact path only.....the above path I give for example

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the specified directory before running the program:

```
cd /path/to/directory && ./process.sh
```